Why are some images rendered correctly and some not?
Since yesterday (?), I noticed that some images show just fine on the Stack Exchange sites but some don't.
For example, the uploaded image of this question on Cross Validated is shown like this (the image is not rendered):



and when I click the link, instead of the image, I see an error message:

oh no, that request didn't look right
RayID: 8a5f31156a098622

But on the same site, the uploaded image of this question is shown just fine:



I first thought it might be related to image size but the second image is fairly large. Why are some images shown correctly while others aren't?
The same thing happens on Stack Overflow too. For example, the images of this post show up just fine, but the images of this post don't.

For what it's worth, all the images that you say are not rendering, are rendering just fine for me.

@CaveJohnson so could it be a caching issue

I actually think it is a dupe of that.  I would guess something needs to kick a cache somewhere, but it's strangely hard to reproduce for staff to fix it.

@JourneymanGeek staff can't fix it, it's a CloudFlare bug. And if the rather small imgur couldn't care less for bugs affecting SE, good luck with the big CloudFlare. (i.e. this won't get fixed.) (On the bright side, at least they appear to not have critical bugs like e.g. CrowdStrike. ;-))

One of the key-points of Stack Overflow was "make the internet a better place". That ship sailed with CoudFlare. It might work against a ddos attack but I have the feeling regular users are impacted more often then they wish to admit.

@rene true, SE pretty much lost control over its own content and the files it serves.
